# How to create object from another object in Python unit test

Tags: python, factory, factory-boy

I'm having trouble understanding unit testing in Python. I have an object, `retailer`, which creates another object, `deal`. `deal` refers to an attribute created in `retailer`, so I'm passing it a reference:

```
class deal():
    def __init__(self, deal_container, parent):
```

The `deal_container` attribute also comes from `retailer`, which calls its own methods to create it.  So how do I create everything I need to easily make a `deal` object?

Do I have to create an instance of `retailer` in my unit test and then call the method in that object that creates `deal`?

Can I use FactoryBoy to create an instance of `retailer` and how do I include the method that creates `deal` in that object?

What's the best way to approach this?

Here's the unit test. I'm setting up the `soup_obj` I need to give deal:

```
class TestExtractString(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['deals_test_data.json']

    def setUp(self):
        with open('/home/danny/PycharmProjects/askarby/deals/tests/BestBuyTest.html', 'r') as myfile:
            text = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
        self.soup_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
        self.deal = self.soup_obj.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'list-item'})[0]

    def test_extracts_title(self):
        z = Retailer.objects.get(pk=1)
        s = dealscan.retailer(z)
        d = dealscan.deal(self.deal,s)
        result = d.extract_string(self.deal,'title')
```

and here's the relevant bit of the `deal` class in `dealscan`. There's a `retailer` class that creates a `deal`, but I haven't even written the bit in `retailer` that creates `deal` yet. I'm hoping I can mock the bits I need for `deal` without having to invoke `retailer` at all, but then how do I deal with the fact that `deal` references `retailer`?

```
class deal():
    def __init__(self, deal_container, parent):
        '''
        Initializes deal object
        Precondition: 0 > price
        Precondition: 0 > old_price
        Precondition: len(currency) = 3

        :param deal_container: obj
        '''
        self.css = self.parent.css

        self.deal_container = deal_container
        self.parent = parent
        self.title = self.extract_string('title')
        self.currency = self.parent.currency
        self.price = self.extract_price('price')
        self.old_price = self.extract_price('old_price')
        self.brand = self.extract_string('brand')
        self.image = self.extract_image('image')
        self.description = self.extract_string('description')

        #define amazon category as clearance_url
        #define all marketplace deals

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def extract_string(self, element, deal):
        '''

        :param object deal: deal object to extract title from
        :param string element: element to look for in CSS
        :return string result: result of string extract from CSS
        '''
        tag = self.css[element]['tag']
        attr = self.css[element]['attr']
        name = self.css[element]['name']
        result = deal.find(tag, attrs={attr: name})
        if result:
            if element == 'title':
                return result.text
            elif element == 'price':
                result = self.extract_price(result).text
                if result:
                    return result
            elif element == 'image':
                result = self.extract_image(result)

        return False
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how these objects are created. The unit test should be focused on what a `deal` does, what its behaviour is. So you can pass in what you like: real objects, `mock` objects or stubs, as long as the test can determine whether deal is behaving correctly.

Comment: Please show us the code of the code of the "unit" you want to test and explain the target of the test.

Comment: That's right. But to test what deal does, I have to create a deal, and it needs a parent because it references an attribute that the parent has. So if I try to create deal outside of its parent object, I get:

AttributeError: 'deal' object has no attribute 'parent'.

I have to create 'deal' so that it doesn't throw that error. Which means I need to create a parent object.

Comment: Added code as per request from @KlausD. Eventually there'll be a self.assert in the unit test to check that it returns a string, but right now I'm just trying to get it to stop the unit test from throwing the error  AttributeError: 'deal' object has no attribute 'parent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the deal object is referencing the parent before it sets the self.parent attribute. Use:

```
self.parent = parent        
self.css = self.parent.css
self.deal_container = deal_container
```

and the `AttributeError` goes away.

As for the question about whether it's good form to use an object to create another object in a unit test, the answer is that you can use mocks, but it's fine to do it this way. Using a helper method to set up the parent object once in setUp is acceptable and will make the code easier to read, and may improve test performance a little.